# Where can I download example templates?

Tags: templating

This will be my first time using Craft, where can I download free templates from or find instructions on how I can create my own templates?

Answer (score 3):

To add to [Matt's answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/15467/4466) there are example templates which contain enough code to get you started in the templates folder `craft/templates`.

There is also a repo on Github called ['HappyLager'](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/HappyLager) which contains more example templates along with annotations.

Answer (score 2):

You won't find downloadable templates like you're used to in other CMS's because the philosophy of Craft isn't about downloading theme's. You should be building your own: https://craftcms.com/docs/templating-overview